# You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I made am update for my app and was trying to release it, but I got this error. I saw articiles saying that this could be because my API levels and such were different or somehting, but everything is exactly the same-

[First release 0.41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQzn.png)

[Update 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ystOw.png)

I build the app in kivy, and made the apk with buildozer, and converted it to aab with a telegram converter.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your 0.5 version `8215` has a lower versionCode then the 0.41 version `82141`. The updated app should have a higher versionCode then the current one

Comment: Oh, what do I do about that?

Comment: In your `app/build.gradle` file there should be `versionName` and `versionCode` specified. `versionName` is in your case 0.5 and `versionCode` 8251. The  `versionCode` should be higher then the current Play store app

Answer (score 4):

The version code for the app bundle that you're uploading is lower (or lesser) than the current app bundle on your play store. Check the version code of the app bundle on play store and increase it. That should be the version code of the app bundle that you're uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably main reason is a.b.c version and difference a.b version. Normally 0.5 > 0.41 but one a.b other a.b.c version code. I think 0.5.0 or 0.5.1 (a.b.c) is solution